# Plotly: Javascript Error: Loading chunk 478 failed

Tags: javascript, python, plotly-python

With Dash installed in Jupyter notebook, running plotly graph example from plotly docs at
https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/ :

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import networkx as nx

# Create Edges

G = nx.random_geometric_graph(200, 0.125)
edge_x = []
edge_y = []
for edge in G.edges():
    x0, y0 = G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos']
    x1, y1 = G.nodes[edge[1]]['pos']
    edge_x.append(x0)
    edge_x.append(x1)
    edge_x.append(None)
    edge_y.append(y0)
    edge_y.append(y1)
    edge_y.append(None)

edge_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=edge_x, y=edge_y,
    line=dict(width=0.5, color='#888'),
    hoverinfo='none',
    mode='lines')

node_x = []
node_y = []
for node in G.nodes():
    x, y = G.nodes[node]['pos']
    node_x.append(x)
    node_y.append(y)

node_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=node_x, y=node_y,
    mode='markers',
    hoverinfo='text',
    marker=dict(
        showscale=True,
        # colorscale options
        #'Greys' | 'YlGnBu' | 'Greens' | 'YlOrRd' | 'Bluered' | 'RdBu' |
        #'Reds' | 'Blues' | 'Picnic' | 'Rainbow' | 'Portland' | 'Jet' |
        #'Hot' | 'Blackbody' | 'Earth' | 'Electric' | 'Viridis' |
        colorscale='YlGnBu',
        reversescale=True,
        color=[],
        size=10,
        colorbar=dict(
            thickness=15,
            title='Node Connections',
            xanchor='left',
            titleside='right'
        ),
        line_width=2))


# Color Node Points

node_adjacencies = []
node_text = []
for node, adjacencies in enumerate(G.adjacency()):
    node_adjacencies.append(len(adjacencies[1]))
    node_text.append('# of connections: '+str(len(adjacencies[1])))

node_trace.marker.color = node_adjacencies
node_trace.text = node_text

# Create Network Graph

fig = go.Figure(data=[edge_trace, node_trace],
             layout=go.Layout(
                title='<br>Network graph made with Python',
                titlefont_size=16,
                showlegend=False,
                hovermode='closest',
                margin=dict(b=20,l=5,r=5,t=40),
                annotations=[ dict(
                    text="Python code: <a href='https://plotly.com/ipython-notebooks/network-graphs/'> https://plotly.com/ipython-notebooks/network-graphs/</a>",
                    showarrow=False,
                    xref="paper", yref="paper",
                    x=0.005, y=-0.002 ) ],
                xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False),
                yaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False))
                )
fig.show()
```

Results in error:

```
Javascript Error: Loading chunk 478 failed.
(error: http://localhost:8888/lab/extensions/jupyterlab-plotly/static/478.f9a7116e09cbfb956212.js?v=f9a7116e09cbfb956212)
```

What's wrong?
​

Comment: for me just restarting the jupyter kernel helped

Answer (score 0):

Installing latest versions of plotly and Jupyter with nothing else in a new environment solved the problem.